# How to convert two very basic functions to callback function

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I have two very basic functions in Javascript

```
function def(){
    console.log("DEF")
}

function abc(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("ABC")
    }, 1000)    
    def();
}

abc();
```

The above functions prints DEF and then ABC. I want to print them in order e.g. ABC and then DEF.

I have basic idea about callback but I am not getting as how to convert above functions to callback function to get the desired output :)

Comment: For some reason people lately keep asking questions where their code clearly and deliberately does X, then ask how not to do X... If you want them to print in order, move `def();` after `console.log("ABC")`

Comment: @ChrisG, Thank you for your comment. My intention is not only to get the desired output but my intention is to get the desired output by converting above functions into callback. My question is how to pass function def as a callback function to function abc.

Comment: There's no such thing as "converting a function into a callback". A function is a function. Your code above already uses a callback, namely the anonymous function you're passing into `setTimeout()`. This seems to be a huge [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/); please explain what your *actual* goal is.

Comment: @ChrisG My goal is to call abc function and pass def function as callback parameter so that when abc function completes its execution, def function gets executed

Comment: And how does the upvoted answer fail to demonstrate *exactly* that?

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, functions are first-class members so you can pass them as parameters into other function just as you would any other object:

```
function def(){
    console.log("DEF")
}

function abc(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("ABC")
    }, 1000)    
}

function withCallbacks(...callbacks) {
    callbacks.forEach(callback => callback());
}

withCallbacks(abc, def); // prints DEF, ABC
```

Answer (score 0):

According to my opinion the answer by @Mateusz is unnecessarily complicated.

If you want to send a callback to any function you have to send it as a parameter to that function.

```js
// Function you want to send as a callback
function def(){
    console.log("DEF")
}

// Function in which you want to call this callback
function abc(callback){
    setTimeout(function(){
        // Log ABC to the console
        console.log("ABC");
        // Call the callback function after the ABC has been logged
        callback();
    }, 1000);
}

// Call the function and pass your callback as parameter
abc(def);
```

Comment: Judging from the previous answer I didn't think that was an intention ... My bad.

Comment: This now seems to be what OP wants, I guess.

Comment: @ChrisG If this is the case, then why I require to pass callback as parameter ? I can simply call def function after console.log inside settimeout as suggested by you in previous comment.

Comment: I still do not know what you are looking for, or why. So what am I supposed to do other than blindly guess what the solution could be? Yes, you can simply call `def()`, but didn't you specifically ask how to pass def as callback...?!